# Sampling uniformly from unit ball around a point on a Riemannian manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, riemannian-geometry, hyperbolic-geometry, sampling

I'm interested in a mechanical procedure (i.e., algorithm) for sampling uniformly from $\{y \in \mathcal{M} : d_\mathcal{M}(x, y) \le 1\}$ for some fixed $x \in \mathcal{M}$, using well-known *tools*. The measure is the one induced by the corresponding Riemannian metric $\{g_x\}_{x \in \mathcal{M}}$.

**When does such an algorithm exist and when is it non-trivial to find one?**

---

We could start from the following schema:

- Sample a tangent vector uniformly from $\{ u \in \mathcal{T}_x \mathcal{M} : \lVert u \rVert_x \le 1 \}$.
- $y = \textrm{exp}_x(u)$, where $\textrm{exp}(\cdot)$ is the exponential map.

Clearly the first step is non-trivial, but that aside, would this approach yield uniform samples in the unit ball around $x$?

And then, is it possible to specify a class of manifolds for which it is possible to *automate* the first step?  Perhaps for embedded submanifolds where we could sample uniformly from the ambient space and then somehow restrict to $\mathcal{T}_x \mathcal{M}$ (and apply the inverse Riemannian metric if different than the inherited one)?

---

Take for instance the Lorentz model of hyperbolic geometry:
$$
\mathcal{H}^n = \{ x \in \mathbb{R}^{n+1} : \langle x, x \rangle_\mathcal{L} = -1, x_0 > 0 \},\quad\textrm{with}\ \langle x, y \rangle_\mathcal{L} = -x_0 y_0 + \sum_{i=1}^n x_i y_i.
$$
The tangent space is $\mathcal{T}_x \mathcal{H}^n = \{ v \in \mathbb{R}^{n+1} : \langle x, v \rangle_\mathcal{L} = 0 \}$.  How could one sample from the unit ball of tangent vectors uniformly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proposed scheme will be ruined by curvature. For example, consider a 2-sphere of radius $1/\pi,$ so that the disc $$\exp(B_1) = \{\exp(u) : \|u\| \le 1\}$$ perfectly covers it. The outer region  $$0.5 \le \|u\| \le 1$$ of the unit disc in the tangent space contains $3/4$ of the measure, so samples drawn using the uniform distribution on  $B_1$ would hit this region $3/4$ of the time; but this corresponds to only half of the sphere in the Riemannian measure. (In your hyperbolic example you would find the opposite - the outer regions have much *more* Riemannian measure than "exponential" measure.)

If we [use the exponential map on $B_1$ as a coordinate system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_coordinates) $x$, this is reflected in the equation $$d\mu_g = \sqrt{\det g}\  d^nx. \tag 1$$ Here $d\mu_g$ is the Riemannian measure associated to $g,$ while $d^nx$ is the standard/Euclidean/uniform measure on the tangent/coordinate space. Thus, unless you happen to have $\det g=1$ in these coordinates, the measures are not the same.

However, equation $(1)$ should tell you how you can sample from $d\mu_g:$ if you have an expression for $g$ in normal coordinates, then $w=\sqrt{\det g}$ is a scalar function you can compute, so we have reduced the problem to that of sampling a weighted measure $d\mu_g = w\ d^nx,$ which you should be able to do programmatically (e.g. via the rejection method).

(One caveat: this only works if the injectivity radius at $x$ is at least $1$; i.e. if the exponential map is injective on $B_1.$ Otherwise, different points in $B_1$ will map to overlapping points on the manifold, so you'd have to restrict to a subset of $B_1$ making the exponential map cover each point in the unit ball exactly once.)

Comment: Thanks, that's very helpful!  I was wondering about your brief comment on the hyperbolic space: the Lorentz model is a semi-Riemannian manifold with constant metric $g = \textrm{diag}(-1, 1, \ldots, 1)$, so $|\det g| = 1$. Doesn't this mean that the above sampling will work as it is?

Comment: Actually, I'm not sure if that makes sense because that metric tensor is the $(n + 1)$-dimensional one used in the Minkowski space, not the $n$-dimensional one at $x \in \mathbb{H}^n$ once a coordinate system is fixed.

Comment: @Călin: your second comment is exactly correct - this method works only when using the "intrinsic" coordinates on the $n$-manifold of interest, not the "extrinsic" coordinates of any $>n$-dimensional space it's embedded in. (Note that it does, however, work for *any* intrinsic coordinates, not just geodesic normal coordinates - so if you a coordinate system in which you can calculate $\det g,$ you should be able to do some "automated" sampling.)

Comment: Could you please just expand a little on how rejection sampling would be used here?  If I understand correctly, the same relationship applies between the Riemannian measure and any other measure (not just the uniform one, $\mathbb{1}_\mathcal{X} (x) / \mathcal{Vol}(\mathcal{X})$). So if I want to sample a pdf $p(x)$ defined on the manifold, I can sample instead $p(x) \sqrt{\det g(x)}$ in some exponential chart (assuming injectivity). But how exactly would I use rejection sampling here?  I first need to find a function that upper bounds it, right?

Comment: @Călin: To sample with the weight $f(x)=p(x)\sqrt{\det g(x)},$ first normalize $\tilde f = C f$ so that its maximum is less than $1$ (ideally equal to $1$), then generate random points $x$ in the chart coordinates and reject them with probability $1-\tilde f(x).$

Comment: thanks, that's what I was thinking of too, but I wanted to make sure. This approach is pretty general but problematic when the measure is very far from being uniform. For instance, in the hyperbolic space $\sqrt{\det g(x)}$ grows exponentially with the norm of the corresponding tangent vector, so the rejection rate would be pretty large. But that's a separate problem.  Thanks once more!